# Checking Output Errors in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout

I wrote this simple program. I know that the `printf()` function in C returns the total number of characters successfully printed so the following C program works fine because any non-zero value is evaluated as `true` in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   if (printf("C"))
   return 0;
}
```

But why does the following C++ program compiles & runs fine? If `cout` is an object not a function, then why is the program giving the expected output?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    if (cout << "C++")
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::cout << "C++";
```

is a function call to [`std::operator<<(std::cout, const char*)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) which returns a reference to `std::cout` which is convertible to `bool`. It will evaluate to `true` if no error on `std::cout` occurred.

Comment: in c++11 the conversion to bool is not implicit

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator returns `cout`. This is why you can chain the `<<` operator like this:

```
std::cout << "Hello" << " " << "C++" << " " << "World!" << std::endl;
```

The returned `cout` will implicitly conver to the value `true` in the if.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but assuming you want your program to exit successfully if and only if the printing succeeded, you should write this in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    if(printf("C") < 0)
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The reason is that `printf` will return a negative number to report errors and –1 is considered “true” as well.

The corresponding C++ program should look like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  if (!(std::cout << "C++"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The reason this works is that calling operator `<<` on `std::cout` returns a reference to the stream *itself*, which also is why things like

```
std::cout << "You've got " << 99 << " points" << std::endl;
```

work.  Each invocation returns a reference to `std::cout` upon which the next invocation is performed.

Now, `std::basic_ios` which `std::cout` is derived from, defines a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).  Since C++11, this is declared as

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

This means that if the stream is evaluated in a boolean context such as as the condition in an `if` statement, it is converted to a `bool`.  The table at the bottom of the [linked page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool#See_also) shows under what conditions the returned `bool` will be `true` or `false`.  In summary: it will return `true` unless an error occurred on the stream.

Before C++11 (when we didn't have `explicit` operators), a `void *` pointer was returned that was non-`NULL` if and only if no errors on the stream occurred.  And again, a `void *` pointer can be evaluated in a boolean context.

Be aware that in both programs shown above, the tests could indicate success but the output may still fail.  The reason for this is that output is usually buffered inside the program and only if enough output is gathered will the operating system be asked to actually do the output.  You can request a *flush* at any time to make this happen *now*.  In C, you would call `fflush` on the respective `FILE *` pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    if(printf("C") < 0 || fflush(stdout) < 0)
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In C++, you can use the `std::flush` constant.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  if (!(std::cout << "C++" << std::flush))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you also want a newline, you can use `std::endl`.  Writing

```
std::cout << "hello, world\n" << std::flush;
```

has about the same effect as writing

```
std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;
```

Note however that output buffering is used for performance reasons so if you routinely flush your buffers after each and every output statement, you might well degrade the performance of your program.

Finally, in C++ you can also ask a stream to throw an exception if an error occurs.  Since I/O errors should not happen during normal operation and repetitively checking for them can clutter your code, this might come in handy.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
  std::cout.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
  try
    {
      std::cout << "C++" << std::flush;
      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  catch (const std::ios_base::failure &e)
    {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

If you want to test whether your program reports the correct exit status for failed I/O, you can try piping standard output to `/dev/full` on POSIX systems.  `/dev/full` is a special file that *pretends* that nothing can be written to it because the file system's capacity is exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is the same as writing

```
cout << "C++";
if(cout){
//do whatever
}
```

It just writes "C++" to cout and checks if your stream is still open.